# How to create datatable with complex header in R Shiny?

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I have a [datatable](https://datatables.net/index) in [R Shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/) and would like to have headers that [span multiple columns like below](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/DataTables-Jquery-Table-Plugin/examples/advanced_init/complex_header.html):

[image]

How can this be achieved in R Shiny?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Theres already example `http://rstudio.github.io/DT/`

```
library(DT)
sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
  class = 'display',
  thead(
    tr(
      th(rowspan = 2, 'Species'),
      th(colspan = 2, 'Sepal'),
      th(colspan = 2, 'Petal')
    ),
    tr(
      lapply(rep(c('Length', 'Width'), 2), th)
    )
  )
))
datatable(iris[1:20, c(5, 1:4)], container = sketch, rownames = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to write this table into excel?

Comment: If u want to know how to export is https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html. Have a look at the `2 Buttons`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at new package from RStudio DT (https://github.com/rstudio/DT)? Here http://rstudio.github.io/DT/ you could find an example of what you need.